# Zend2: Override the Application Config with a module config

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I use BjyAutorize and I want for a special module another Identity Provider. I can load the Provider without a problem when I comment out the configuration in my global config file from the Application. But I can not override the configuration by my module config. Is there a way to do that? I don't want to put in every module the config from `bjyautorize`.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to add some examples / code on your current situation and on what you have tried so far. Makes understanding your question a lot easier :)

Comment: in some easy words. I have the Application config. And every modul has also his own config. For a special modul the configuration is different to tha one in the Appliactionconfig. So i write a config for the Modul.(same options as in the Application config). But the config from the Application is no overwritten by the config in the Module. :) How can i do that?

Comment: I found the solution. https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/tutorials/config.advanced.html#manipulating-merged-configuration

Comment: The question was clear enought, it is a configuration override issue.